# Modify Eclipse Search

Tags: eclipse, search

I recently installed Ganymede SR2 and wanted to search something.
I pushed CTRL - H which opens the search view and used the File search. However, what I encountered is that the folders test-build and exploded-archieves where also searched, and I want to disable searches for those folders.

I only wanted to search the source code, not what is generated. Does anybody know how I can do this in Ganymede?
I didn't have this problem in Europa.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a working set that only includes your source directories. When using the search you can sepcify the working set as the scope (near the bottom of the search dialog box).

To do this press Ctrl+H to open the sreach box, then in the scope area click the Choose... button, this will open a dialog where you can manage working sets.

Answer (score 0):

I used Eclipse Kepler.

Limit search to only source files i.e only to **.java** files by entering "**.java**" in `File name patterns(Separated by commas):` field present in **File Search** tab of Search dialog.

Add more more file name patterns separated by commas like : `*.java, *.xml, *.properties, *.txt` etc